# compare string variables in perl

Tags: string, perl

I have an if clause in perl, where as condition I need to compare two variables if they match as strings. But my code doesnt work and the strings never match:

```
if(trim($file) eq trim($fields[0])) {
print "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO";
}
```

For the definition of trim I have used:

```
sub trim($)
{
   my $string = shift;
   $string =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;
  return $string;
}
```

Moreover I have used this before for the variables to compare.

```
my @fields= split(/\;/,$_);
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: That's a trivial subroutine and a trivial check, they should work as expected. The error lies with your input. Use the `Data::Dumper` module to see what your variables *really* contain (as opposed to what you think they contain).

Comment: in particular, `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper($file); print Dumper($fields[0]);`  (the useqq option is very important to make whitespace more apparent)

Comment: It would be easy enough to test in `sub trim` to see what `$string` is. Add a `print "$string\n";` after the shift.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, so your strings are different.

To find the differences, I recommend the following code since it will reveals differences that might not be noticeable by just printing the strings:

```
use Data::Dumper;
{
   local $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
   print Dumper($file, $fields[0]);
}
```

---

By the way, the following is more elegant and possibly faster:

```
sub trim {
   my $string = shift;
   $string =~ s/^\s+//;
   $string =~ s/\s+\z//;
   return $string;
}
```

And IIRC, the following is even faster (for a drop in readability):

```
sub trim {
   my $string = shift;
   $string =~ s/^\s+|\s++\z//g;
   return $string;
}
```